# sudo apt-get install scala not found on ubuntu

Tags: scala, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I am completely stumped by why this simple sudo install is not working.
I am running ubuntu 16.04 on virtualbox on windows, and when i run the command

sudo apt-get install scala

command, I get the E:Unable to locate package scala error.
I have sudo apt-get update beforehand, and sudo apt-get install default-jdk worked 
perfectly fine.

Does anyone have any idea why my ubuntu can't find the scala package?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to `apt-get` Scala, but you have to add the bintray repository to your sources file.

```
deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian / # access to Scala deb packages
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against installing Scala with `apt install scala`, as the versions can be out of date (on Ubuntu 18.04 I got v2.11, while v2.13 is available). Instead go to the Scala webpage and install from there. If you want to be able to run

```
$ scala
```

and get the REPL, one option is to look for the .deb package on the install page and use that